# Erro Deprecated: Function ereg()

Tags: php, regex

No *script* que eu instalei deu esse erro:

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in /home/u844214382/public_html/funciones.php on line 98 Deprecated:

**Código na linha 98:**

```
if (ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$", $mensaje)) {
```

Existem ainda outras chamadas a `ereg` no mesmo [arquivo](http://pastebin.com/t9yeDTZV).

Comment: Seria um *warning*, certo? Quer dizer que na versão do PHP que você está usando (qual é?), o `ereg` é considerado obsoleto. Você precisa usar outra função, ou mandar o php silenciar os warnings.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Então, o ideal seria usar [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) em vez do `ereg`.

Comment: Já usei mais não funcionou, Poderia colocar no Código? por que eu não sei muito de php.

Answer (score 3):

`ereg_*` foi marcada como obsoleta (*deprecated*) no PHP 5.3. Para arrumar esse erro, basta trocar por [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match). Por exemplo:

```
ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$", $nombre_usuario)
```

Troque por:

```
 if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$/", $nombre_usuario)){
      ----------^                       ^----------- 
 inicio do delimitador                   fim do delimitador
```

Para corrigir o seu código é necessario mudar a ereg nas funções:

1. ValidaMail()
2. shout()
3. uc()

Basicamente o que muda é que você obrigado a colocar sua regex entre algum delemitador, no caso foi `/`. Outro ponto é que `ereg` é baseado nas regex do Unix equanto `preg_*` é nas de Perl (ver [modificadores PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

Comment: Deu esse warning: preg_match(): no  ending delimiter '^'

Comment: Parece que o delimitar está no lugar errado.

Comment: Eu coloquei assim if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$/", $nombre_usuario)); {

Comment: Em linha de if, não vai `;`. Remova o `;` antes da chave. `$nombre_usuario)); {`

Comment: Ainda não resolveu.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, estava faltando uma ` \ `.

Comment: Onde coloco o \? Desculpa ae porque estou fazendo muitas perguntas é porque sou muito noob, Se poder me diz o código completo sem erro.

Comment: @user7329 Não me leve a mal, mas tente entender os problemas que estão acontecendo. Assim que você resolver o problema dessa linha, irão aparecer outros (tem vários `ereg` no código que você postou). O negócio deste site não é resolver o problema particular de cada um, mas criar um repositório de perguntas e respostas que possam ser úteis para múltiplas pessoas com problemas parecidos. Quanto mais isto aqui se tornar um diálogo para resolver os detalhes do seu código, menos adequado ao site será (daqui a pouco o sistema vai sugerir que vocês continuem a discussão no chat).

Comment: Eu sei cara mais to tentando resolver esse erro desde manhã e não consigo!

Comment: Ainda da o mesmo erro http://homebux.com.br/

Comment: Qual é a linha 98?

Comment: É, Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in /home/u844214382/public_html/funciones.php on line 98 The Field admin is not Valid

Comment: Coloca a linha de código 98, isso ai é a mensagem de erro.

Comment: if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$/", $mensaje)) {

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver!

Answer (score 2):

Sua versão do php está atualizada e te informando que o ereg não funciona mais.

Você pode substituir pela preg_match() que é uma alternativa.