# Pegar data e hora de uma string

Tags: php, regex

Estou querendo "filtrar" a `string` para obter apenas a data que está nela, a `string` está nesse formato:

> SSC Napoli v Dnipro - Quinta-Feira 07/05/2015 16:05 Horas

O Quero pegar é apenas o `07/05/2015 16:05`, usei o `explode`:

```
$datas = eregi_replace('[.\A-Z\-]','', $datas);
$datas = explode("/",trim($datas));
$dia = substr($datas["0"], -2);
$datas = $dia."/".$datas["1"]."/".$datas["2"]."";
return $datas;
```

Mas o problema, é que quando o nome do time que está na string tem número, tipo:

> SSC Napoli2 v Dnipro - Quinta-Feira 07/05/2015 16:05 Horas

Obviamente irá dar errado, queria usar algo em `regex` se tivesse como, pra extrair essa data e hora, sou fraco em `regex` e já tentei algumas coisas mas não funcionou!

***Atualização***:

Consegui fazer funcionar também utilizando o seguinte algoritmo:

```
eregi_replace('[.\A-Z\-]','',substr($_GET["link"],-22));
```

Mas se alguém tiver algo mais bem elaborado, favor responda!

Comment: Matou a pau!!! valeu! precisava busca o ano em um campo de texto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar essa *regex* para capturar a data, use a função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) ou [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php), pois [eregi_* foi depreciada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11870/91) a partir do php 5.3

```
$str = 'SSC Napoli v Dnipro - Quinta-Feira 07/05/2015 16:05 Horas';
preg_match('/(\d{2}\/)+(\d{4})\s*(\d{2}:\d{2})/', $str, $match);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($match);

echo 'data completa: '. $match[0];
```

[Exemplo - Ideone](http://ideone.com/1bz2or)

**Explicação:**

`(\d{2}\/)+` Esse grupo(o conteudo parentesses) captura o dia e mês e a barra. `\d` permite apenas que digitos seja capturados, `{2}` significa que o número de capturas.

`(\d{4})\s*` Esse grupo captura o ano seguindo de um ou mais espaços(`\s*`)

`(\d{2}:\d{2})` Captura a hora que é composta de dois digitos(`\d{2}`) seguida de dois pontos e por fim mais dois digitos.

Answer (score 3):

Uma expressão regular alternativa: *(\d{2})-./[-./]+(\d{4})\s([\d:]+)*.

```php
$texto = "SSC Napoli v Dnipro - Quinta-Feira 07/05/2015 16:05 Horas
          SSC Napoli v Dnipro - Quinta-Feira 08-06-2015 17:05 Horas
          SSC Napoli v Dnipro - Quinta-Feira 09.06.2015 18:05 Horas";

preg_match_all('~(\d{2})[-.\/](\d{2})[-.\/]+(\d{4})\s([\d:]+)~', $texto, $data);
```

Para recuperar os valores faça:

```php
foreach($datas[0] as $data) echo "Data completa: {$data}\n";
foreach($datas[1] as $dia)  echo "Dia encontrado: {$dia}\n";
foreach($datas[2] as $mes)  echo "Dia encontrado: {$mes}\n";
foreach($datas[3] as $ano)  echo "Ano encontrado: {$ano}\n";
foreach($datas[4] as $horario) echo "Horário encontrado: {$horario}\n";
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/l1Z44I)