# não consigo trazer os dados do banco de mais de uma tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou aprendendo a fazer um admin, e então criei algumas tabelas no banco de dados, mas não sei por que só consigo inserir e deletar dados da tabela de usuários e da de projetos não. Deve ser algum erro bobo, abaixo mostrarei como eu criei meus códigos.

Tabela que está certa com o php que traz os dados

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`nome` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`foto` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

HTML

```
       <?php
        // Seleciona todos os usuários
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY nome");

        // Exibe as informações de cada usuário
        while ($usuario = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
            // Exibimos o nome e email
            echo "<p><b>Nome:</b> " . $usuario->nome ." </p>";
            echo "<p><b>Email:</b> " . $usuario->email . "</p>";
            // Exibimos a foto
            echo "<figure><img src='fotos/".$usuario->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /></figure>";
            echo "<iframe width='400' height='200' src='". $usuario->video ."' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            echo "<form action='deleta.php' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='". $usuario->id ."'>
                    <input type='submit' name='deletar' value='deletar' />
                </form>";
        }


        ?>
```

Tabela que está errada com o php que traz os dados

```
    CREATE TABLE `tb_projetos` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `texto` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    `foto` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

       <?php
        // Seleciona todos os usuários
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_projetos ORDER BY nome");

        // Exibe as informações de cada usuário
        while ($usuario = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
            // Exibimos a foto
            echo "<figure><img src='fotos/".$usuario->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /></figure>";
            echo "<textarea>".$usuario->texto."</textarea>";
            echo "<form action='deleta-fotos.php' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id_proj' value='". $usuario->id_proj."'>
                    <input type='submit' name='deletar' value='deletar' />
                </form>";
        }


        ?>
```

Este é o código php que conecta com o banco e traz os dados, na tabela que funciona o código é o mesmo e só muda os campos

```
            <?php
            include "conexao.php";

            // Se o usuário clicou no botão cadastrar efetua as ações
            if ($_POST['cadastrar']) {

                // Recupera os dados dos campos
                $texto = $_POST['texto'];
                $ft_projetos = $_FILES["foto"];

                // Se a foto estiver sido selecionada
                if (!empty($foto["name"])) {

                    // Largura máxima em pixels
                    $largura = 2000;
                    // Altura máxima em pixels
                    $altura = 1080;
                    // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes
                    $tamanho = 1000;

                    // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
                    if(!eregi("^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$", $ft_projetos["type"])){
                       $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
                    } 

                    // Pega as dimensões da imagem
                    $dimensoes = getimagesize($ft_projetos["tmp_name"]);

                    // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida
                    if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
                        $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
                    }

                    // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida
                    if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
                        $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
                    }

                    // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido
                    if($arquivo["size"] > $tamanho) {
                        $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
                    }

                    // Se não houver nenhum erro
                    if (count($error) == 0) {

                        // Pega extensão da imagem
                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $ft_projetos["name"], $ext);

                        // Gera um nome único para a imagem
                        $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

                        // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
                        $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;

                        // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
                        move_uploaded_file($ft_projetos["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);

                        // Insere os dados no banco
                        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_projetos VALUES ('', '".$texto."', '".$nome_imagem."')");

                        // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso
                        if ($sql){
                            echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
                        }
                    }

                    // Se houver mensagens de erro, exibe-as
                    if (count($error) != 0) {
                        foreach ($error as $erro) {
                            echo $erro . "<br />";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione qual o erro está ocorrendo, seja um código ou um printscreen.

Comment: Patrick Maciel, Não tem como eu fazer isso pois não há erros exibidos na tela, eu vou postar o php que faz todo o processo pra vcs analisarem

Comment: Para facilitar o debug, sempre rode suas consultas assim: `$res = mysq_query('SELECT .....') or die(mysql_error);`

Comment: Qual versão do php usar? [ereg](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11870/91) foi depreciada a partir do php5.3 é bom trocar ela por preg_match quando puder.

Comment: eu estou usando o phpmyadmin versão 4.2.11

Comment: rray, Eu coloquei o or die(mysql_error); e não deu nenhum erro na tela, e é isso que me deixa mais intrigado pois a tabela de usuários funciona perfeitamente e os códigos só mudam os campos e nome da tabela não sei pq não funciona

Comment: No começo do arquivo coloque: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. No `die()` esqueci de colocar o parentesse, o certo é a assim: `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24686/discussion-between-user4451-and-rray).

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se vc percebeu esse pequeno detalhe:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_projetos ORDER BY nome");
```

Na segunda parte, vc está criando uma Query ( Requisição ) ao banco de * ( tudo ) da tabela *tb_projetos*,  ordenando pelo campo **nome**, `...ORDER BY nome");`.

Porém, sua tabela de projetos ( *tb_projetos* ) não possui o campo *nome* :

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_projetos` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`texto` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`foto` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

---

Dá uma olhada nisso extraido dessa [Página](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp):

> Note: If a column is AUTO_INCREMENT (like the "id" column) or TIMESTAMP (like the "reg_date" column), it is no need to be specified in the SQL query; MySQL will automatically add the value.

Comment: Yuri Calistrato, Eu retirei o ORDER BY nome da segunda tabela e mesmo assim não insere nada no banco e não da nenhum erro na tela

Comment: No caso, a tabela não está sendo exibida? De acordo com o código, ele faz uma consulta no banco e exibe. Não tem inserção nesse código. Não está faltando nada a acrescentar a pergunta? Nessa exibição ele coloca os dados dos projetos na página e um pequeno formulário para remoção. Ele não está removendo? Ou algo diferente? Está meio dúbio.

Comment: então, em tb_projetos os dados não estão sendo inseridos, talvez se tivesse sendo inseridos seriam exibidos normalmente como na tabela de usuários que difere pouca coisa desta tabela é isso que esta acontecendo

Comment: O que está acontecendo, segundo seu código é `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_projetos VALUES ('', '".$texto."', '".$nome_imagem."')");` onde você está passando um caracter vazio no inicio de `VALUES('',...`, quando se é utilizado AUTO_INCREMENT não há necessidade de colocar nada e você está passando um caracter.

Comment: ok eu retirei o espaço vazio e continua não inserindo os dados nessa tabela, o engraçado é que na tabela de usuários está com este espaço e tudo funciona corretamente 
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ('', '".$nome."', '".$email."','".$video."', '".$nome_imagem."')"); Essa é a inserção da tabela de usuários

Comment: No exemplo da [Página](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) explicita o comando de inserção com `INSERT INTO <Nome da tabela>(campo_01,campo_02,campo_03) VALUES (valor_01,valor_02,valor_03);` , faça o teste explicitando as colunas. Talvez resolva.

Answer (score 0):

Sua tabela "tb_projetos" não possui o campo "nome", remova o "ORDER BY nome".

Comment: Kayo Bruno, Como eu havia dito para o Yuri eu retirei e continuou a mesma coisa

Comment: Você também está tentando acessar $usuario->id_proj quando na verdade era pra ser $usuario->id

Comment: ja corrigi isto também e continua não inserindo, este id que vc mencionou era pra eu deletar o registro da tela