# Solução/alternativa para eregi_replace obsoleto

Tags: php

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\ajax\paginator.inc.php on line 202
```

Esse é uma linha de um script que faz paginação com php+mysql+ajax

Linha 202:

```
$_pagi_sqlConta = eregi_replace("select[[:space:]](.*)[[:space:]]from", "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", $_pagi_sql);
```

Boa parte das querys estão obsoletos, e eu estou adaptando do mysql para mysqli. Porém, a 'eregi_replace' eu não conhecia até o momento, e depois de pesquisar, não consegui achar uma solução/alternativa para ela.

Comment: [Erro Deprecated: Function ereg](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11870/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua por **preg_replace** e faça o teste.

```
$_pagi_sqlConta = preg_replace("/select[[:space:]]'\(.*\)'[[:space:]]from/", "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", $_pagi_sql);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\ajax\paginator.inc.php on line 202

Eu estava tentando exatamente ela agora, mas recebi o erro acima e também não consigo resolver.

Comment: Editei, tente agora.

Comment: Parece que o erro do preg_replace foi solucionado. Porém, um erro ocorreu linhas abaixo: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\wamp\www\ajax\paginator.inc.php on line 208. Linha 208:  $_pagi_totalReg = mysql_result($_pagi_result2,0,0);//total de registros

Comment: Ai é outro erro, não sei te dizer o que pode ser pois não estou vendo como está implementado.

Comment: Tudo bem, entendo. Estarei marcando a resposta como correta, pois realmente resolveu a questão, e o que veio depois é consequência. Creio que seja melhor criar uma outra pergunta, não é? Ah... obrigado!