# Erro php 5.4 iniciando classe feita no php 5.2

Tags: php, classes

> Fatal error: Class 'func' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\painelnovo\classes\config.php on line 15

config.php linha 15

```
include_once "class.func.php";
$func = new func;
```

class.func.php

```
<?php
class func
{
    function is_valid_string($string) {

        $cfgBadChars='`~!@#$%^&*()+-_=[]{};\'\\:"|,/<>? ';

        if (empty($string))
            return true;

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($cfgBadChars); $i++):
            if (strstr($string, $cfgBadChars[$i]))
            return true;
        endfor;

        return false;
    }

    # function filter co mot gia tri la $ojb cai ma ban se kiem tra
    function char_filter($ojb)
    {
        $badchars='Ý`~!@$%^()+-_=[]{}\'\\:"|,/<>? '; # Nhung ky tu khong cho phep duoc len danh sach tai day
        for ($i=0;$i<strlen($badchars);$i++){
            $ojb=str_replace($badchars[$i],"",$ojb);

        }

        return $ojb;
    }

    function getInt($o)
    {
        $err=false;

        for($i=0;$i<strlen($o);$i++)
            if(!eregi("^[0-9]",$o[$i])) $err=true;

        if($err)
        {
            ereg ('[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*', $o, $cutInt);
            $o=intval($cutInt[1]);
            if(!$o)
                return false;

            return $o;
        }

        return $o;

    }

    function checkSkillPoints($level,$kind)
    {
        $SP=intval(( ($level-10) /2))+1;

        if($level>=55) $SP=$SP+1;
        if($level>=70) $SP=$SP+1;
        if($level>=80) $SP=$SP+2;

        $EP=intval(( ($level-60) /2))+1;

        return ($kind=='SP')?$SP:$EP;
    }

    function checkStatePoints($level)
    {
        $points=(($level)*5)-5;

        for($i=80;$i<=$level;$i++)
        {
            $points+=2;
        }
        for($i=90;$i<=$level;$i++)
        {
            $points+=3;
        }

        if($level>=30) $points=$points+5;
        if($level>=70) $points=$points+5;
        if($level>=80) $points=$points+5;

        return $points;
    }

    function char2Name($classNum)
    {
        switch ($classNum)
        {
            case "01":
                $charClassName="Fighter";
            break;

            case "02":
                $charClassName="Mechanician";
            break;

            case "03":
                $charClassName="Archer";
            break;

            case "04":
                $charClassName="Pikeman";
            break;

            case "05":
                $charClassName="Atalanta";
            break;

            case "06":
                $charClassName="Knight";
            break;

            case "07":
                $charClassName="Magician";
            break;

            case "08":
                $charClassName="Priestess";
            break;

            default:
                return false;

        }

        return $className;
    }


    function char2Num($className)
    {
        switch ($className)
        {
            case "Fighter":
                $classNum=1;
            break;

            case "Mechanician":
                $classNum=2;
            break;

            case "Archer":
                $classNum=3;
            break;

            case "Pikeman":
                $classNum=4;
            break;

            case "Atalanta":
                $classNum=5;
            break;

            case "Knight":
                $classNum=6;
            break;

            case "Magician":
                $classNum=7;
            break;

            case "Priestess":
                $classNum=8;
            break;

            default:
                return false;


        }

        return $classNum;
    }


    function charResetState($class)
    {

        switch ($class)
        {
            case "Fighter":
                $charStr=pack('i', 28);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 6);
                $charTal=pack('i', 21);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 17);
                $charHea=pack('i', 27);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Mechanician":
                $charStr=pack('i', 24);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 8);
                $charTal=pack('i', 25);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 18);
                $charHea=pack('i', 24);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Archer":
                $charStr=pack('i', 17);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 11);
                $charTal=pack('i', 21);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 27);
                $charHea=pack('i', 23);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Pikeman":
                $charStr=pack('i', 26);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 9);
                $charTal=pack('i', 20);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 19);
                $charHea=pack('i', 25);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Atalanta":
                $charStr=pack('i', 23);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 15);
                $charTal=pack('i', 19);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 19);
                $charHea=pack('i', 23);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Knight":
                $charStr=pack('i', 26);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 13);
                $charTal=pack('i', 17);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 19);
                $charHea=pack('i', 24);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Magician":
                $charStr=pack('i', 16);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 29);
                $charTal=pack('i', 19);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 14);
                $charHea=pack('i', 21);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

            case "Priestess":
                $charStr=pack('i', 15);
                $charSpi=pack('i', 28);
                $charTal=pack('i', 21);
                $charAgi=pack('i', 15);
                $charHea=pack('i', 20);
                $charStateStr=$charStr . $charSpi . $charTal . $charAgi . $charHea;
            break;

        }

        return $charStateStr;


    }

    function charResetHair($class,$model)
    {
        switch ($class)
        {
            case "Fighter":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\b001.ini").pack("h*",00);
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\tmh-b02.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Mechanician":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\a001.ini").pack("h*",00);
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\tmh-a02.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Archer":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\d001.ini").pack("h*",00);
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\tfh-D01.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Pikeman":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\c001.ini").pack("h*",00);
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\tmh-c02.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Atalanta":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\mb001.ini");
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\Mfh-B02.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Knight":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\ma001.ini");
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\Mmh-A03.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Magician":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\md001.ini");
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\Mmh-D01.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;

            case "Priestess":
                $modelName1=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\mc001.ini");
                $modelName2=pack("a*","char\\tmABCD\\Mfh-C01.inf").pack("h*",00);
            break;
        }

        $model=($model==1)?$modelName1:$modelName2;

        return $model;
    }

    function charResetSkill()
    {
        $tier0_1=pack("h*",00);
        $tier0_2=pack("h*",00);
        $tier0_3=pack("h*",00);
        $tier0_4=pack("h*",00);

        $tier1_1=pack("h*",00);
        $tier1_2=pack("h*",00);
        $tier1_3=pack("h*",00);
        $tier1_4=pack("h*",00);

        $tier2_1=pack("h*",00);
        $tier2_2=pack("h*",00);
        $tier2_3=pack("h*",00);
        $tier2_4=pack("h*",00);

        $tier3_1=pack("h*",00);
        $tier3_2=pack("h*",00);
        $tier3_3=pack("h*",00);
        $tier3_4=pack("h*",00);

        $skillStr=$tier3_4.$tier0_1.$tier0_2.$tier0_3.$tier0_4.
            $tier1_1.$tier1_2.$tier1_3.$tier1_4.
            $tier2_1.$tier2_2.$tier2_3.$tier2_4.
            $tier3_1.$tier3_2.$tier3_3;

        return $skillStr;
    }

    function charResetMastery()
    {
        $tier0_1=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier0_2=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier0_3=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier0_4=trim(pack("i",5000));

        $tier1_1=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier1_2=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier1_3=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier1_4=trim(pack("i",5000));

        $tier2_1=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier2_2=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier2_3=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier2_4=trim(pack("i",5000));

        $tier3_1=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier3_2=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier3_3=trim(pack("i",5000));
        $tier3_4=trim(pack("i",5000));

        $masteryStr=$tier3_4.$tier0_1.$tier0_2.$tier0_3.$tier0_4.
            $tier1_1.$tier1_2.$tier1_3.$tier1_4.
            $tier2_1.$tier2_2.$tier2_3.$tier2_4.
            $tier3_1.$tier3_2.$tier3_3;

        return $masteryStr;
    }

    function charFullMastery()
    {
        $tier0_1=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier0_2=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier0_3=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier0_4=trim(pack("i",10000));

        $tier1_1=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier1_2=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier1_3=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier1_4=trim(pack("i",10000));

        $tier2_1=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier2_2=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier2_3=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier2_4=trim(pack("i",10000));

        $tier3_1=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier3_2=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier3_3=trim(pack("i",10000));
        $tier3_4=trim(pack("i",10000));

        $masteryStr=$tier3_4.$tier0_1.$tier0_2.$tier0_3.$tier0_4.
            $tier1_1.$tier1_2.$tier1_3.$tier1_4.
            $tier2_1.$tier2_2.$tier2_3.$tier2_4.
            $tier3_1.$tier3_2.$tier3_3;

        return $masteryStr;
    }

    function numDir($name)
    {
        $character=array
        (
            "0"=>"48",
            "1"=>"49",
            "2"=>"50",
            "3"=>"51",
            "4"=>"52",
            "5"=>"53",
            "6"=>"54",
            "7"=>"55",
            "8"=>"56",
            "9"=>"57",

            "a"=>"65",
            "b"=>"66",
            "c"=>"67",
            "d"=>"68",
            "e"=>"69",
            "f"=>"70",
            "g"=>"71",
            "h"=>"72",
            "i"=>"73",
            "j"=>"74",
            "k"=>"75",
            "l"=>"76",
            "m"=>"77",
            "n"=>"78",
            "o"=>"79",
            "p"=>"80",
            "q"=>"81",
            "r"=>"82",
            "s"=>"83",
            "t"=>"84",
            "u"=>"85",
            "v"=>"86",
            "w"=>"87",
            "x"=>"88",
            "y"=>"89",
            "z"=>"90",

            "A"=>"65",
            "B"=>"66",
            "C"=>"67",
            "D"=>"68",
            "E"=>"69",
            "F"=>"70",
            "G"=>"71",
            "H"=>"72",
            "I"=>"73",
            "J"=>"74",
            "K"=>"75",
            "L"=>"76",
            "M"=>"77",
            "N"=>"78",
            "O"=>"79",
            "P"=>"80",
            "Q"=>"81",
            "R"=>"82",
            "S"=>"83",
            "T"=>"84",
            "U"=>"85",
            "V"=>"86",
            "W"=>"87",
            "X"=>"88",
            "Y"=>"89",
            "Z"=>"90",
        );

        for($i=0;$i<strlen($name);$i++)
        {
            $total+=$character[$name[$i]];
            if($total>=256)
                $total=$total-256;
        }

        return $total;
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Parece que o arquivo foi incluido com o caminho ou nome errado. Detalhe `eregi` foi depreciada no php5.3 o ideal é trocar por `preg_*`

Comment: deve ser este o problema, pois no php 5.2 a classe funciona normal

Comment: O erro diz `Class 'func' not found in`, `eregi` não é causa a do problema (ainda).

Comment: pior que era '=', mas estou tendo problemas em outras partes tambem, o codigo foi feito no php 5.2

Comment: Troca `include_once "class.func.php";` por `require_once "class.func.php";`, é provável que o local do include_path esteja diferente.

Comment: cero poderia me ajudar em outro problema ? se possivel me add no skype ou hangout

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sabe me dizer como ficaria com preg_match ?

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki isso responde: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11873/3635 ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o preg_match ficou correto obrigado. mas ainda estou tendo problemas em outras partes do script